# Creating a Navigation without coding

Tags: sxa, responsive-design

Is it possible to create a navigation like Logo in the left side, Menu pages in the middle and CTA at the right of the page.

This is what I want

[image: Navigation]

Has anyone done something like this without doing any coding. Just using the existing Navigation component or using a partial page design.

Comment: have you tried using separate components for image, navigation and link in one partial page and provide the grid size accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a partial design and use 3 components to achieve this.

For the logo you could use Image, Rich Text or Promo - for the CTA a Rich Text or Promo could also be ok. And a navigation component in the middle.

Using the grid settings will be enough to get them aligned as needed (e.g. set the logo and cta to 3 and this leaves you 6 for the navigation). You can find more information about setting the grid here: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/100/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/change-the-layout-of-a-rendering.html

Note that you can set different values for different devices if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using partial design without code change.
For reference please follow menteioned steps as below link http://succorpoints.blogspot.com/2018/12/sxa-partial-design-creation-part-2_9.html